# Ionic strange behavior

Tags: css, ionic4

Hi I'm trying to set gradient background to ionic tool bar ,

```css
.logo-toolbar {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 25%, #004b7a 35%, #004b7a 68%, #004b7a 100%) !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #f48726 !important;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<ion-toolbar class="logo-toolbar">
  <ion-title>
    <img src="../../assets/img/sys.jpg" class="logo"/>
  </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

with above code border is showing but background is not set but when i add color to ion-title then it works,

```
 <ion-toolbar  color="pink" class="logo-toolbar">
    <ion-title>
      <img src="../../assets/img/sys.jpg" class="logo"/>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

what is happening here?

Comment: cool does seem to be a bit of a hack .just for the record the correct way to do background colour here is _____            `--background  linear-gradient(to right, #fff 25%, #004b7a 35%, #004b7a 68%, #004b7a 100%)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ,

Ionic uses a custom property for setting background for the tool bar which always has higher precedence ,need to override it,

```
--background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 25%, #004b7a 35%, #004b7a 68%, #004b7a 100%) !important;
```

P.S : Dont know how the hack worked.